# Unequal sample sizes

Tags: unbalanced-classes, biostatistics, anosim

I have 11 years of data ranging from May-November. Based off of environmental data, I broke these months into two "seasons". I called these seasons summer (May-September) and fall (October and November). Each month was sampled 10 times for every year. So my summer season would have 50 samples whereas fall would have 20 samples for every year. When I conduct analysis on these data to test for differences between the seasons across the years (ANOSIM, SIMPER, etc), what do I need to do to factor in the unequal sample sizes within the seasons?